# What's the preferred way to explicitly handle exceptions by the default exception handlers?

Tags: java, exception

In my (graphical) Java application in certain cases I want the user to see an exception, because there's nothing better I can do.

My first idea was to just let the exceptions bubble, until the application-wide default exception handlers catch it, but in some cases it's not possible (mostly because of the `ActionListener` interface)

What's the preferred way to redirect an exception to the default exception handler?

Is there a method to call the default handlers (either `Thread.defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` or `sun.awt.exception.handler`) or is it better to just explicitly call a method on my default exception handler class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one or more exception types for all non-technical exceptions.  Make sure it extends `RuntimeException`.

If you encounter a checked exception that should be notified to the user nonetheless, wrap them in your own types (but try to give a decent message, not just 'nullpointer' or something).

In your gui layer, add a layer that catches your custom exception type.  I suggest you use aop for this, but you can also do this the hard way.  Then just show the error message to the user, and log the stack trace.

Comment: Wrapping checked exceptions in runtime exceptions was the key. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The default exception handlers simply do about this:

```
System.err.println("Exception on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
ex.printStackTrace();
```

If this is right for your application, you can do this yourself. But if you want to show it to the user, maybe a dialog with a (J)TextArea is better.